# Why won't .getPropertyValue() return a value for the "borderRadius" property?

Tags: javascript, css

Here is the function:

```
function lastmenuborder() {
    var articleparent = document.getElementById('article').parentNode;
    var articlestyle = window.getComputedStyle(articleparent,null).getPropertyValue('borderRadius');
    alert (articlestyle);
}
```

I get no value, yet the css for the parent node is:

```
div#mainbody div.placeholder {
    border-radius: 3px;
}
```

What would I have to change to return "3px"? All help greatly appreciated; I am still a newb at JavaScript.

Comment: could you check this please? alert(articleparent.style.borderRadius);

Comment: @Sebas I get no value. Does this mean that I've not referenced the right element?

Comment: If my interpretation of the CSS is correct, it looks like the div.placeholder is getting the border radius styling not, it's parent div#mainbody... this could be why

Comment: Are you sure? According to my browser's element inspector, div.placeholder has the style. And CSS applies to the last element in the list.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For `getPropertyValue()`, you use hyphens instead of camelCase.

This works in Chrome...

```
.getPropertyValue('border-radius');
```

But Firefox seems to require specific corners using this syntax...

```
.getPropertyValue('border-top-left-radius');
```

Answer (score 0):

**getComputedStyle** is not supported on IE8 below, to fix this use:

```
if (!window.getComputedStyle) {
       window.getComputedStyle = function(el, pseudo) {
           this.el = el;
               this.getPropertyValue = function(prop) {
               var re = /(\-([a-z]){1})/g;
               if (prop == 'float') prop = 'styleFloat';
               if (re.test(prop)) {
                   prop = prop.replace(re, function () {
                       return arguments[2].toUpperCase();
                   });
               }
               return el.currentStyle[prop] ? el.currentStyle[prop] : null;
           }
           return this;
       }
   }

var elem = window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById('test'), "");
alert(elem.getPropertyValue("borderRadius"));
```