# Correctly setting and inquiring background color in Chrome (from Javascript)

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome

Following is a Chrome dev tools console session of manipulating text to having a red background.

One may notice the difference between `background-color` and `backgroundColor` which may seem to present an odd relationship in this case.

```
> document.getElementById('38').style.backgroundColor = 'red'
"red"

> window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById('38')).getPropertyValue('background-color')
"rgb(255, 0, 0)"

> window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById('38')).getPropertyValue('backgroundColor')`
null
```

How can this be explained?

The text does turn red in the browser, but the api may seem a bit quirky.
What may I be doing wrong?

Comment: Thanks @StefanoSanfilippo for showing how to code-highlight a chrome console session there!

Answer (score 2):

According to [Mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.style#Notes) `.style` is used to modify CSS properties of an element through a "style" attribute of an element

`<div style="background-color: red"></div>`

But it does not give you a full representation of styles state of an element i.e. `.style` does not contain all computed styles.

[Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Properties_Reference) you can see available shortcuts for CSS properties that are used with `.style`.

In this list in first column for background we have an original name of CSS property - `'background-color'` and a shortcut that is used with `.style` - `'backgroundColor'`

Using `.getPropertyValues(prop)` seems to use a value from first column `prop = 'background-color'`, that is pretty similar to CSS original property name

For `.style[prop]` you use a value from second column `prop = 'backgroundColor'`.

[Question with a similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10803023/why-wont-getpropertyvalue-return-a-value-for-the-borderradius-property)

Comment: Thanks for the great and well-rounded answer including the link to a most similar issue! (how did you figure the meaning of each column at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Properties_Reference).

Comment: To complete this answer it seems that the `setProperty` method is consistent with the `getPropertyValues` method. E.g. `document.getElementById('10').style.setProperty('background-color', ...)` - using the same property name as the getter method `getPropertyValues` and thus they make a more developer friendly a couple together, at least, in Chrome.