# How to get border-width using ComputedStyle in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, getcomputedstyle

The following command

```
window.getComputedStyle(box).getPropertyValue("border")
```

is returning

```
"0.994318px solid rgb(255, 0, 0)"
```

How do I get border-width using ComputerStyle? Is there a way to replace the "border" argument by other one so it would, in the above case, output

```
0.994318px
```

Comment: So read `"border-width"` instead of border?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Similar to [Why won't .getPropertyValue() return a value for the "borderRadius" property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10803023/why-wont-getpropertyvalue-return-a-value-for-the-borderradius-property)

Specify the exact CSS property you want, so 'border-width'

Edit: As @HereticMonkey pointed out (which I missed in the linked post), in Firefox, you need to get very granular with your property. So in the case of border-width, you need to get the exact border, e.g. border-bottom-width.

Comment: The answer to that question seems to indicate the need for getting `'border-top-width'`, `'border-bottom-width'`, etc...

Comment: @HereticMonkey That would also work, but if border is the same on all sides, `border-width` returns a single value

Comment: I'm talking about the accepted answer on the question you've linked to, where it says "But Firefox seems to require specific corners using this syntax...

`.getPropertyValue('border-top-left-radius');`", which says to me, if the OP is using Firefox, they may need to get each side individually.

Comment: @HereticMonkey well throw me in a black hole and call me dense, you're right. Updated.

Answer (score 2):

To get the 'border-top-width' from class:

```
<style>.mystyle{border:8px solid grey;padding:10px;}</style>

<div id="xyz" class="mystyle">just testing</div>

<script>
    var mydiv = document.getElementById('xyz');
    var borderTop = parseInt(getComputedStyle(mydiv).getPropertyValue("border-top-width").replace('px',''));
    console.log('borderTop:'+borderTop);// -> 8
</script>
```

Comment: Isn't `var borderTop = parseInt(getComputedStyle(mydiv).getPropertyValue("border-width").replace('px',''));` going to work too?

Comment: Yes BlueSkies, my example shows how to get top border, there are 'edge' cases where the border won't be around all 4 sides or might be a different size to other sides.

Comment: BTW, I like how you "get rid" of the "px" by `replace('px', '')` when obtaining only the number

Comment: @BlueSkies A better example would have been to use margin, I recently had a case where the top margin was +1 and bottom was -8. I was trying to compute x,y position and offsetHeight includes padding but doesn't include margin, once I could allow for the margin my calculation worked.

Comment: I'm curious why the output is "0.994318px solid rgb(255, 0, 0)" and not "1px solid rgb(255, 0, 0)"...

Comment: Can also use `parseFloat` for numbers that might not be integers.